# Connect wallet to dapp automatically in internal wallet browser

Tags: wallets, web3-providers, eip

I am working on a ethereum wallet and building an in-app webview where user can open dapps inside dapp itself (like trust wallet, family, etc).

I am injecting a Provider (inspired from [trust-web3-provider](https://github.com/trustwallet/trust-web3-provider/tree/master)) into `window.ethereum` which
is being picked up by dapps and want to automatically connect wallet as soon as dapp opens. I have tried to add wallet address as soon as the dapp loads, trigger `eth_requestAccounts` event manually, but nothing worked.

I know that many wallets do it like **Trust Wallet** and **Family** but can't figure out how? Can anyone assist here?